# oracle sql:how to convert string datetime to specified format

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I've been searching around for a while now, but I can't seem to find the answer to this small problem.

how to convert string 06-JUL-89 to datetime 06/07/1989?
I've tried with code like the following:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(BORN,'DD-MON-YY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

however, the result shows wrong: to be 06/07/2089? how do i solve the problem?

Comment: Is the data type of your `BORN` column really a string (e.g. `varchar2(9)`)? Or is it actually already a `date`, and your client is just currently showing it in that format via your session NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting? If it is data type `date` then you just need to convert that to a string for display, e.g. `to_char(born, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

Answer (score 1):

With `RR` format model.

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('06-jul-89', 'dd-mon-rr'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') result from dual;
                                                 --
RESULT                                          here
----------
06/07/1989

SQL>
```

---

By the way, it looks as if you store date values as strings. If so, don't do that - switch to `DATE` datatype (as soon as possible).

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have the problem of year 2k :

- `TO_DATE('06-jul-89', 'dd-mon-yy')` => 06/07/2089
- You must use `TO_DATE('06-jul-89', 'dd-mon-rr')` => 06/07/1989

Comment: That would make the year 0089, not 1989 (or 2089).